# joomla displaying page set for registered access

Tags: php, joomla, access-control

Our website has a an article which is only available to registered users and is in the Category "Private" which runs a php script to display (low grade) personal information

The URL displayed when logging in and following the menus looks like this https://example.org/index.php/listsecretpage

Somehow a search engine found and indexed this page and then it could be viewed without being logged in using the URL like this https://example.org/index.php/2-features/445-secretpage

I assume that 2-features means this pages is the category called "features". Given my page is now in "Private" could this be a caching issue from before the category of this page changed nearly a year ago?

So some questions:
Perhaps most important - why did Joomla serve a page which was marked as Registered access only to non-registered users (esp. search engines)?

How can I stop Joomla serving (selective) pages which based on category as in index.php/2-features/dont_show_this_page ?

I could not see anything in the Maintenance: Clear Cache which related to my page - in fact very few seemed cached. Can one inspect the Joomla cache to clear selective pages or see which pages are cached?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer to your questions.

1. I don't believe that the issue is related to Joomla cache.
2. I believe that your menu is set as private but your article is set as public. Could you please check this one?
3. There are many ways to stop serving private pages. For example, you can set a RewriteRule in the .htacces using the cookie which Joomla set when an user does the login. Neverthless, this ways aren't sure at 100%. Moreover, it is better to solve the problem at its source (see my answer above).

I hope I was of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the respones both menu and article have "Registered" access. I am wondering whether the page was found by search engines before I tightened up the security last year. Even though the article is Registered that page could still be viewed using the link https://example.org/index.php/2-features/445-secretpage until I added a check of login status in the PHP script last week.

Comment: If you changed the status last year it could possibly still be in the Google (etc) cache.  If Google is the issue, one thing you should do if you haven't is use webmaster tools to send a new site map and to ask Google to re-spider the site.

Comment: If ceemjay have tried to clean browser's cache and the url still appears, search engines (Google, Bing, etc.) don't have anything to do with this issue.